# CSV export based on ajax

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, logic

So I have a problem which I've been stuck on. I have a page, so say a table of student's and all their information: grades, gender etc. Now I have a feature on that page that can filter out a attribute. So, through ajax I re-render the table if I want to just see all the boys. Now I have a download csv link at the bottom of the page, but I want to make it dynamic based on the filtering. I am not sure how to go about this.

I've tried using gon, gon.watch but to no success.

Comment: Send filtered params to your csv link and filter results before download

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard for us to help debug a verbal description of your code. Can you show us what you've actually tried and all the relevant snippets? We can then copy/paste and alter that code and show you examples that might work for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should use something like https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack for making safe search. Then in your views:

```
= form_for(@search) do |f|
  = f.label :gender
  = f.select :gender, ["Male", "Female"]
  = f.submit "Filter"
# table of users
= link_to "Download CSV", students_path(format: 'csv'), class: 'download-csv'
```

One JS code will reload table whenever filters changed, and other code will update download link params

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.download-csv').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = this;
    var formData = $('form').serialize();
    link.href = link.href.toString().replace(/\?.+$/, "?" + formData + "&format=csv");
    location.href = link.href;
  });
);
```

And in your controller you just render CSV when `request[:format] == 'csv'`